# How to forward traffic from one LAN router through another router then to the original gateway?

Tags: networking, routing, nat, subnet, gateway

I have two routers connected to  my ISP within one town in the subnet **192.168.0.0/24**.Router A can reach router B successfully. I have higher bandwidth on router A than B. I would like to make **A the default gateway for router B** so that all **requests are forwarded through A**  so that all traffic appears to come from router A to the ISP default gateway. I don't know how to achieve this kind of **routing/NAT.**
I'd appreciate any ideas very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a site to site VPN or GRE tunnel. Router B has to connect via a VPN tunnel (for such static cases *I* suggest using wireguard) to Sita A (where Router A is located), and then route the traffic over Router A into WAN.

Router B also probably needs to provide a different subnet than router A, or else you might stumble into difficult terrain regarding DHCP (if you use it at all) and other "there is only one router"-shenanigans

Comment: I am using huawei HG8546M on which am sure I have limited VPN or tunnel options. Is'nt there a way to NAT requests from B through A?

Comment: You can also setup the VPN between two devices inside Networks A and B, altho that is a lot more difficult, as router B has to route all traffic to that client device inside its own network, and route all traffic of that devices into its WAN at the same time. Sorry, there is no simple way to just "NAT" something,

Comment: let me work with this. Thanks man.